# Not changing root password in Centos 7

Tags: centos, password, root

I have a CentOS 7 server and I couldn't log in to it because I forgot the root password.
So I changed this password, but still did not work when I tried to log in using this new one.

I'm using HP proliant d380 g7 with CentOS 7.

Comment: A server - are we talking login via `ssh`? Is root-login permitted in `sshd.conf`?

Comment: You can't log in, but you can change the password? What exactly is it that you're doing? What results and what did you expect to result instead?

Answer (score 2):

Try reset the root password using the grub command line :

1. Press `e` in the grub menu in order to edit the boot command.
2. Update the line start with `linux16` and replace the option `ro` with `rw init=/sysroot/bin/sh`
3. Press `Control+x` to start on single user mode
4. After the boot you are logged in as root. Type `chroot /sysroot` to mount the root file system.
5. Update the root password with `passwd` command and type the new root password. I suggest to set a very easy password.
6. Run the command `touch /.autorelabel` to update the SELinux.
7. Then type `exit` and finally reboot the system with `reboot`.

After the reboot you are able to login as root with the password set in the step 5.